# AlertDialog should be type Dialog

Tags: java, eclipse, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Closely following the skeleton shown here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#

All over this page, they use declarations like this one:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle(R.string.pick_color);
       .setItems(R.array.colors_array, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           // The 'which' argument contains the index position
           // of the selected item
       }
    });
    return builder.create();
}
```

The data type of this method is "Dialog" but the builder used, and therefore the return type of the method is "AlertDialog". Eclipse understandably tells me that these are incompatible, and won't compile my code when I try to do something similar.  It also won't let me cast the  result of the builder.create() call to type Dialog, so no work-around there.  How can I fix this and get my code to compile?
THanks.

Answer (score 0):

You just copy and past? Code from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html# works without any mistakes. The AlertDialog is subclass of Dialog and it is not mistake(returns alertdialog when method type is dialog.)May be you forgot about "extends DialogFragment"?